# How to deal with localization? Is there a standard I should follow?

Tags: php, localization, currency

I'm trying to make a set of classes to deal with localization (mostly the currency part, but also language).

I can imagine how the logic could be, but I don't know what names to use for the different languages and currencies. I have seen there are many ISO standards for this, which one should I pick?

Anyway here's the logic I was thinking of in case you can help with this too:

I would have a Money class, with amount and currency attributes. On creation, the object receives the amount and the currency (an object provided by the localization class maybe?). You can add to or multiply the amount. The add method takes another money object as parameter, and if it has a different currency, a convertion is made automatically.
Somewhere an array is stored with all the standard names such as en_US and USD, relating them appropiately, and also relating them to the equivalent in USD as a scalar value. Money objects should be able to print the amounts in different formats, such as $ 1000, or U$s, etc.

- Is this a good way to deal with this?
- Which standar should I follow?
- Do you know any already existent, decoupled php libraries to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the new [`intl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) module. Although the [`ICU`](http://site.icu-project.org/) library as a whole is not a standard, its components are. And it's compatible with C, C++ and Java.

Comment: ICU uses CLDR data from Unicode ( http://cldr.org ) and ISO 4217 currency codes, including information on historical (over-time) currency changes

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Zend Framework's component [Zend_Locale](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.html). It does all the work for you without needing to write your own class(es).

Comment: too bad it's tightly coupled with the rest of the framework. I tried to use it by modifying all its harcoded require paths, but it kept asking for more and more classes, such as cache, registry, etc etc. It also has lots of static calls, which is one of the reasons Zend is being rewritten. I hope Zend 2 will be as amazing as it seems from what we can read in its roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I wouldn't suggest mirroring .Net, but check out the way they do localization. It is easily one of the best small-scale implementations of it I've seen.

Not great for highly dynamic applications along the lines of iGoogle, but fantastic for the headings on static forms, currency, and the like.