# What is the preferred method of localization in Zend 2?

Tags: localization, zend-framework2

I am looking for a tutorial on the preferred method of handling localization in Zend 2, but so far I haven't been able to find any. The best I could find is [this page](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.i18n.translating.html), which doesn't explain the practical process of implementing localization (specifically, application messages) in detail, or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259735/how-to-deal-with-localization-is-there-a-standard-i-should-follow), which was asked before the release of Zend 2 and is now outdated.

If given a choice presented on that page, say I pick GNU Gettext as a translation format. Is there any tutorial on localizing a ZF2 application in that case?

Or, say I store the text of the pages on my site in a database table, for example

```
CREATE TABLE `page` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` blob,
  `locale` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `creator` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `pagecreatorfk_idx` (`creator`),
CONSTRAINT `pagecreatorfk` FOREIGN KEY (`creator`)
REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

How would I go with providing localized messages then?

Comment: Can you define localization a little more? For example, are you just looking to translate text to different languages, time formats, currency formats, etc...

My first recommendation though is to use GetText translation format and I wouldn't store it in a database, but rather text files, and I would also setup cache for them too.

Comment: I meant primarily the translation of various messages, including elements such as the form labels or button captions, but also the contents of the pages on the site, and also date, time and currency formats, of course. The particular site in question is a simple site with some static pages and the possibility of editing them through the web application itself. Though I would also appreciate some pointers on how this is done in larger and more complex applications compared to smaller ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, for starters you'll need a translation program such as http://www.poedit.net/

Here is how I have my setup:

In your Module folder create another folder called "language".

Open your module.config.php and add the following:

```
'translator' => array(
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'        => 'gettext',
            'base_dir'    => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'     => '%s.mo',
            'text_domain' => 'account'
        )
    )
)
```

What makes things easy for me is to create a language.php file and add lines like this:

```
echo _('text_to_translate_here');
```

When you configure your PoEdit you'll scan this file which will add the translation id's to PoEdit. Now you can add the real text that you want to be displayed and upon save it will output 2 files like account.mo and account.po. The only file you need to upload to your language folder is the account.mo

Since I use translations all over my application I've added the factory to my global.php file:

```
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        )
    )
);
```

In my view.phtml file I'll now be able translate:

```
<?php echo $this->translate('text_to_translate_here', 'account'); ?>
```

Now if you don't want to use textdomains as I have shown in my example of the module.config.php then all translations will by default use the "default" textdomain. So you could do this instead:

```
<?php echo $this->translate('text_to_translate_here'); ?>
```

This will also work for FormLabels: (This will output Priroity as the label name)

```
<?php echo $this->formLabel($this->form->get('prio')); ?>
```

If you want to translate Form objects using a textdomain other than "default" then you could add this to your view.phtml

```
$this->formSubmit()->setTranslatorTextDomain('account');
```

Now your Submit FormLabels will use that textdomain instead of the default textdomain. The same goes for any other type of Form Object. Just replace formSubmit with the element type.

Let me know if this helps out or if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Looking at your answer, the only thing which isn't immediately clear is how to handle dynamic text (the content of the pages editable by user). That would have to be done dynamically, and I imagine outside of the boundaries of Gettext (or not?), as the admin of the site needs to be able to provide and edit translations of the editable parts of the pages in several languages on the fly. An example of a similar concept can be seen on Linked.in, when providing resumes in different languages. I will provide an update if I encounter problems with localizing static parts of the pages.